# issue in dynamic Form List with collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd, ant-design-pro

I am stuck on implementing dynamic form submit. Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-meitner-pifys).

I am receiving data from backend

```
    const dataFromBackend = [
      { id: 2, start: "2022-01-04T08:00:00.000Z", money: "500" },
      { id: 3, start: "2022-02-04T08:00:00.000Z", money: "1500" }
    ];
```

And trying to show that data to user in `Collapse`, and in collapse there are 2 forms (first one is for date, second one for money) that user can edit.

Also I have `add` button which allow user to add new collapse with empty inputs (first one is for date, second one for money).

After all user can add as much collapses as he/she wants and send all data to backend.

Here is the [photo](https://ibb.co/N6FhkCX) of final result.
P.S. forms count in picture a little bit different, don't worry about that ;)

I try to implement that in this way as says in antd [docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List):

```
    const BasicInformation = () => {
     const { Panel } = Collapse;

      const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      };

      const dataFromBackend = [
        { id: 2, start: "2022-01-04T08:00:00.000Z", money: "500" },
        { id: 3, start: "2022-02-04T08:00:00.000Z", money: "1500" }
      ];
      return (
        <Form onFinish={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
         <Form.List name="values">
           {(fields, { add }) => {
             return (
                <>
                  <Button
                    type="dashed"
                    onClick={() => {
                      add();
                    }}
                    block
                  >
                    Add
                  </Button>
                  <Collapse
                    accordion
                    style={{
                      background: "rgba(25, 103, 210, 0.08)",
                      border: "none"
                    }}
                  >
                    {dataFromBackend.map((data, idx) => (
                      <Panel
                        style={{ border: "none" }}
                        header={data.money}
                        key={`${data.id}`}
                      >
                       <div>
                         {fields.map((field) => (
                          <>
                             <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, "start"]}
                            label="Start"
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "start"]}
                          >
                            <DatePicker />
                          </Form.Item>
                          <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, "money"]}
                            label="Money"
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "money"]}
                          >
                            <Input />
                          </Form.Item>
                        </>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </Panel>
                ))}
              </Collapse>
            </>
          );
        }}
        </Form.List>

        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          send
         </Button>
        </Form>
      );
   };
```

But it not working correctly, when I am clicking on `add` button the forms were adding in collapse, but I need to add new collapse with that two forms.

Please help me fix that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Collapse` component on every iteration on the fields, also you need to convert `start` property in your `dataFromBacked` to moment object because antd's `DatePicker` works with moment object as value. like this:

```
{fields.map((field, i) => (
    <Collapse
      key={i}
      accordion>
      <Panel ...>
        <Form.Item
          name={[field.name, 'start']}
          label="Start"
          fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'start']}>
            <DatePicker />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name={[field.name, 'money']}
          label="Money"
          fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'money']}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
      </Panel>
    </Collapse>
))}
```

BTW in order to initialize your list with `dataFromBackend` you can use it as `initialValue` attribute on `Form.List` component. I've implemented an example [Here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g) you can check it out.

Comment: you are amazing, thanks for your help, it was works for me

Comment: @someone Glad I could help.